# Delete / Remove Speaker Notes from PowerPoint Presentation

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2007

How do you remove the speaker notes from a powerpoint presentation?

Answer (score 2):

In PowerPoint 2007

From the Microsoft Office Button (big button, top left) select Prepare, Inspect Document.

After scanning Document Inspector will notify you if notes exist and allow you to clear them.